# Handsontable with React, ordering resets everytime the state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

I have a react application which uses handsontable. I added ColumnSorting to my table which works fine till an event is triggered which updates the state. When that happens the sorting gets reset to the initial state. Is it possible to maintain ordering when state changes in the component?

I am attaching a JSFiddle below.

To reproduce the error:

- click on a column header to sort the table.
- click the update state button on the bottom

Thank you for your help!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qk0a2cf/)

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
        this.handsontableData =Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(6, 10);
}

save() {
    this.setState({test:'123'})
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HotTable settings={{
          data: this.handsontableData,
          colHeaders: true,
          rowHeaders: true,
          columnSorting: true
        }}/>
        <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>Update State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

Comment: Just purely based on how React works, if you update the state, `render` is called and your components re-render. If ordering is not part of `App` state, I don't see how you could maintain it, since you don't have access to how `HotTable` works.

Comment: Is it possible (recommended?) to update the data every time the sort order changes?

Comment: It seems like your `save` is not doing anything useful, so unless you're updating the state with something that changes the table's data, I would refrain from state changes.

Comment: in my project i have various events happening that modify the state, in this example i just put in the necessary code to only reproduce the issue